# Setting the Default Permissions level for site when granting permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, default-value

Using SharePoint Online. I'm granting permissions to a library.

- Go into a library
- Cog -> Library Settings
- Click Permissions for this document library
- Click Grant Permissions
- Click Show Options

After the Show Options is expanded, the Select a permission level is always defaulted to Edit. I want this to be defaulted to Contribute. Is there a way to do this? I will this to apply to every library in the site collection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to set the default value. Open your site in SharePoint Designer, edit the master page and add the following code block to the header section of your master page:
(Pay attention that currently custom master page is not supported in the modern Site, below method just work in classic site)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_DdlSimplifiedRoles").val("role:1073741827");
    $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_DdlGroup").val("role:1073741827");
})
</script>
```

You can use F12 to find the "role:XXX" of Contribute in your environment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately I'm using modern sites, also have over 15,000 lists in my tenant that I would need to do this for, and any future libraries created.